# Boundary conditions for a complicated diffusion equation problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mathematical-physics, boundary-conditions, diffusion, boundary-terms

*this is my first post/question, so any constructive criticism on how to ask questions better is also welcome*

I have this problem:
we have an infinite(in z axis) cylindrical tube, from $R1$ to $R2$ with some initial temperature $f(r)$. We fill the inner space $r= 0$  to $R1$ with water that is always well mixed (no radial dependency). The outer wall is insulated. Calculate T(r,t).

Solutions for the diffusion equation are:

$T(r,t) = A * T(t)$ in water

and

$T(r,t) = (B_n J_0(kr) + C_n Y_0(kr))e^{k^2Dt}$ in the tube.

From the boundary condition at the outer wall you get the quantization condition for $k_n$.

Another boundary condition is that the heat flux at R1 corresponds to the change of temperature in the water. This is an equation that connects $A$, $B$ and $C$. What are the other boundary conditions? (I need two more as there are 3 constants) I don't think continuous temperature at R1 is one, as water is always well mixed. Also there is no continuity of the current for the same reasons. Is there something I am missing?

Thank you